# Xcode 8: UI Testing, Neither element not any descendant has keyboard focus

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8, xcode-ui-testing

I've recently started to use UI testing within Xcode. I was able to record the test and play it back and it worked perfectly fine. I recently changed the accessibility labels for textFields to make the test look cleaner by giving it a better name.

However, now when I record the UI test and play it back again to test it, I get an error "***Neither element not any descendant has keyboard focus.***". I've attempted to uncheck hardware keyboard as mentioned in other posts, but that doesn't work for me.

```
    //test login with username and empty password
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let elementsQuery = app.scrollViews.otherElements
    let emailtextfieldElement = elementsQuery.otherElements["emailTextField"]
    let passwordtextfieldElement = elementsQuery.otherElements["passwordTextField"]

    emailtextfieldElement.tap()
    passwordtextfieldElement.tap()
    emailtextfieldElement.tap()
    app.typeText("wayne@test.com")
    passwordtextfieldElement.tap()
    app.buttons["Login - signInButton"].tap()
```

Anybody know the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeText` on `emailtextfieldElement` instead of `app`.

```
let emailtextfieldElement = elementsQuery.otherElements["emailTextField"]
emailtextfieldElement.tap()
emailtextfieldElement.typeText("wayne@test.com")
```